# Uno Platform:Font not displaying correctly on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, fonts, uno-platform

I am starting with a proof of concept Uno App.  I have implemented a Navigation View that works fine in UWP and IOS.  The issue exists in the android version where the glyph is not displayed correctly.  I copied the font from windows into the the Assets/Fonts directory in the Android section.  Here is a relevant piece of code

```
                    <NavigationViewItem Content="Connect" x:Name="B">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"   Glyph="&#xEBDB;"/>
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>
```

I am using the Segoe MDL2 Assets font as above.  I am probably just not understanding the examples.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you set the `Build Action: AndroidAsset` after copy it to `Assets/Fonts` directory ?,you could refer to [Font in Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#android)

Comment: I did set the Build Action to AndroidAsset as you mentioned.  I saw the page you mentioned and could give that a try- I was hoping to do everything in xaml for now.  Do you feel it is more advantageous to do this in the c sharp file?

Comment: I think they are equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Try using the fully-qualified path, eg:

```xml
<FontIcon FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/Segoe MDL2 Assets"   Glyph="&#xEBDB;"/>
```

You can find guidance on using custom fonts with Uno Platform in the docs: https://platform.uno/docs/articles/using-uno-ui.html#custom-fonts

Comment: I have that a try and it did not help.  I am thinking about using pathicon instead.  It will be more difficult to make the paths - but I tried it on one and it sends to work.

Comment: There's also a new blog post about this: https://blog.mzikmund.com/2020/01/custom-fonts-in-uno-platform/

Comment: Thank you for the blog post- it is very well written.  Unfortunately it does not fix the issue.  I did switch the Uno packages to the development and it solved one issue- but not this one.  I tried another font- font awesome and it did not work either.  I believe the issue is with the control itself as the IOS, UWP, and WASM parts work correctly.